# How do i redirect one subfolder in one domain to another subfolder in another domain preserving path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

heres the situation
i have the domain 1

```
http://domain-1.com/somefolder-1
```

sometimes the domain 1 have someinformation after the subfolder

```
http://domain-1.com/somefolder-1/PRESERVE-THIS-PATH
```

What i need is to send the domain-1/somefolder-1

to another domain

```
http://domain-2.com/anotherfolder-1/PRESERVE-THIS-PATH
```

preserving the path if present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess of `domain-1`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^somefolder-1(/.*)?$ http://domain-2.com/anotherfolder-1$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```